# Comedy movie/TV show featuring a lactating girl convincing a boy to consume her breast milk

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, comedy

I want to identify this movie/TV show I watched the trailer of. It was going to be on air on TV. So here are the details:

**When did I watch it**

I watched it about 7 years ago and movie must have been **released after 1999-2000**.

**Language and Country**

It was an English language movie and American/British.

**Genre of the movie/TV show**

By watching the trailer, it looked like a comedy movie/TV show.

**Disclaimer**

This is not a porn ID. It was just a comedy movie like American Pie.

**Plot Details**

In the trailer, there is a girl and boy (perhaps the lead stars). The girl's breasts are lactating. Because of too much milk, her shirt gets kinda wet. She has to take the milk out, but does not want to waste it. So she asks the boy to suck'em and takes her shirt off. But the Boy refuses, so she takes milk in a jug, and asks him to consume it all. That is where trailer ends.

I have googled about it, but couldn't find. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you remember the scene's location? (Was it in a room? Outside? Among people?) And what the characters looked like or how old they were?

Comment: It was in the room, kitchen perhaps. It looked like a kitchen. There were only two of them. And I can't say age confim. Perhaps 30's.

Comment: Got a vague memory of this happening in a Wayans movie.

Comment: ...also of course something similar happened in (very much not a comedy) The Grapes of Wrath.

Comment: @T.E.D. It was not that old.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems you saw a clip from the [season 2 premiere](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0661170/combined) of *Nip/Tuck* from 2004 where Gina, whose baby Christian helps her with, is lactating and doesn't want to ruin her silk shirt, so she asks Christian to suck out the milk instead.  Eventually, Christian reluctantly relents and is then offered a glass of milk with his cake by *another* woman (Julia) holding a jug. The clip is below [**Warning: A Bit Graphic**]: